# How can I use ChevronRight icon in xaml(I know how to put it inside button)?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml

I have code like this

```
         <Grid Style="{StaticResource SubSection_Grid_Style}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource Textblock_SubSection_Style}"
                    Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Settings_HeaderNotifications, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
                <FontIcon Grid.Column ="1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE00F;" />
            </Grid>
```

However, I cannot see the ChevronRight icon using this method. Then I put the chevronright icon into button like this

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{StaticResource XX.FontSize.ExtraSmall}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE00F;" />
```

Then I can see the icon. I'm wondering how to show the ChevronRight icon without using button.

Comment: you question needs a major edit, its very unclear what the actual question is

Comment: @MikeT Just edited, sorry for my poor explanation

Comment: I wouldnt do that with a font and glyph. Use a path instead. There are hundrets of similar paths out there.

Comment: Interesting, and don't know.  For situations like this, you can use a tool like Snoop to examine the UI at runtime.  That sometimes gives you hints as to why you're not seeing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xE00F;" />
```

This worked for me without having to use any external libraries or packages.